# Adding onClick function with Javascript doesn't go through

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I am trying to add an onClick attribute to a button created with Javascript. Obviously I am using Javascript to add it, however it won't go through because when I inspect the element on the web page it doesn't show an onClick attribute there. This is the code I have to create the button

```
var buttonExponent = document.createElement('button');
buttonExponent.innerHTML = '^';
buttonExponent.onclick = function(){appendExpr(this.className);};   <---This is my problem
buttonExponent.className = 'button operator ' + expression.id + ' top';
buttonExponent.style.marginTop = '0px';
buttonExponent.style.marginLeft = '-6px';
container.appendChild(buttonExponent);
```

The rest of the functions work fine and everything, however the onClick attribute simply won't get added on. I have tried doing it multiple ways, but none of them work

EDIT: Figured I should add what the output is on the webpage, the element has this HTML

```
<button class="button operator expr1 top" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -6px;">^</button>
```

When it should be looking like this

```
<button onClick="appendExpr(this.className);" class="button operator expr1 top" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: -6px;">^</button>
```

Comment: What happens when you click it?

Comment: Nothing, the onClick attribute doesn't get added

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/AMB4T/1/

Comment: Wait, why does the onClick attribute not show up?

Comment: Show up where exactly ?

Comment: Oh, you're expecting to see it in the DOM inspector, but it's a property so it's not added as an attribute, and it doesn't need to be.

Comment: Oh, ok. I thought that because I didn't see it there it meant it wasn't getting added. That's confusing. Its good now, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modifying the `element.onclick` DOM property doesn't modify the element's `onclick` attribute. They are two separate pieces of data, confusingly.

To set the attribute, use `element.setAttribute('onclick','code here')`.

Comment: That's correct, the property and the attribute is not the same thing, expect in this case it is, both should work and this doesn't solve anything.

Comment: No, the attribute is a string, while the property is a function.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, the problem was that by setting the onClick through element.onClick I was setting the property without the attribute, and the properties don't show up when inspecting the element on the webpage, so I had to set the attribute for it to show up